# Manual Null-Termination on Unix using Intel x86 Assembly (address vs value in memory operands)?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, null-terminated

I have to be missing something obvious here, but I can't seem to find the end of a string.

My code starts off with a few calls that read as follows:

```
; read user input
;
    mov     eax, SYSCALL_READ       ; read function
    mov     ebx, STDIN              ; Arg 1: file descriptor
    mov     ecx, buf                ; Arg 2: address of buffer (buffer is input)
    mov     edx, BUFLEN             ; Arg 3: buffer length (defined as 256)
    int     080h

    mov     [rlen], eax             ; save length of string read
```

The professor gave us a shell program to work from, but I've got a pretty good handle on most of it. What's throwing me off is that I was of the impression that rlen should now contain the length of the string I'm using, but when I type the following:

```
mov     byte[esi + rlen], 92            ; add a zero
```

I get a segfault. Same, also, if I use [buf + rlen]. Neither buf nor ESI on their own cause a segfault, so it seems to me that rlen isn't doing what I think it is.

Anyone able to help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: Your code doesn't show putting the buffer pointer into `esi`. Are you sure that's what it's set to? And how does moving a `92` add a zero? If later in the code you are processing the string in a way that assumes a zero termination, that could be running past your valid memory space.

Comment: Oh, yeah my bad. I was using backslashes as an easy way to see if I was having any effect on the string. As for ESI, my bad again; the line 'mov  esi, buf' is the line just above where I was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems with your code:

```
mov     byte[esi + rlen], 92
```

- `92 != 0`.  The terminating zero byte, `'\0'`, is an integer with value zero.
- rlen is an address, not the value at that address.

So test that read returned >= 0, then use the return value that's still in a register.

```
; read(2) return value still in eax

test eax, eax
jl  read_error    ; handle errors on eax less than zero.

mov esi, buf      ; mov imm32 to get the address in a register

mov  [rlen], eax  ; store return value to the rlen global

mov  byte ptr[esi + eax], 0
;or:  mov byte ptr [buf + eax], 0  ; works because the buffer is statically allocated.

jz  handle_EOF    ; flags still set from test
```

Or if you copied ecx to a register that's not clobbered by the read system call, you can use that instead of reloading.

Within a function, think of local variables as living in registers, and memory locations only somewhere you can spill them if you run low on registers.  Don't be like a non-optimizing compiler and store/reload your variables when you don't need to.  This is easier on an architecture like x86-64 with 16 regs;  32bit x86 is pretty badly limited, and has an obsolete args-on-the-stack ABI.

---

If your buffer was already zeroed, you could just pass read(2) a count that was one smaller than your buffer size.  Zeroing just the last byte after read returns is better, though.

Comment: To check if I understand, the return value in `eax` is the length, right? So if I were hell-bent on using `rlen`, would it work to write `mov   ecx, [rlen]` and then `add   ecx, buf`? What I'm figuring here is that I'm retrieving the value to which `rlen` points and then making it useable in my address.

Comment: Yes, read's return value (in eax) is the length if it's >=0.  zero means EOF, negative means error.  You shouldn't be loading `[rlen]` back into a register, that's just silly.  You still have the value you stored in eax.  But yes, you could add the address of the buffer to the byte count, as you describe.  You could also write `mov [buf + eax], 0`, and never bother to load buf's address into a register at all.  The key point is that `[buf]` is a memory operand, `buf` is an immediate constant whose value is the address of buf.  `buf` isn't a pointer (it's a global array).

Comment: In C, we're talking about `char buf[1000]`, not `char *buf`.  Note that `mov esi, buf` is `mov r32, imm32`.  It's not a load (as in load from an address).